# cd Desktop gives an error no such file/ directory in terminal

Tags: linux, macos, command, cd

In Terminal, on mac, when i use the cd Desktop to view files through the terminal i get an error "no such file or directory"
When i checked the current working directory, it shows I'm in /home/
I do not understand why suddenly it doesn't work. 
I tried using a .profile file to have some alias and path change. Could this change in .profile file cause this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try use cd (with no parameters) for jump to your home directory which should be /Users/username. Then use cd Desktop. Alternatively you can do "cd ~/Desktop"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make a desktop folder in the home folder, then open the command prompt

Also, try the **" cd desktop "** command you will not get an error. Always remember the **case-sensitive** words before running Command.